# Xamarin.Forms: Specific Info.PList based on specific configuration

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am trying to setup my project that swaps out the Info.PList file based on the active configuration (Debug, Custom_ReleaseA, Custom_ReleaseB).
I've seen similar question posted a few times, but I haven't found a solution that seems to work. I just did this with specific Manifest in Android project, and It works well, but I've no idea to do this for iOS project.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Does using [Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) help you? Besides, here is [a way that edit the .csproj file](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85867/multiple-build-targets-visual-studio#latesthttp://).

Comment: Solved! Thx for the tip.